# Finding the general form of the span of 2 matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question asks $\text{span}(A1,A2)$

$$A1 =\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$$

I began by calculating $c_1[A1] + c_2[A2]$ then converting it into a matrix and row reducing.  I found the restrictions where the stuff after the augment must = 0 then plugged those back into \begin{bmatrix}w&x\\y&z\end{bmatrix} and got the wrong answer. Could anyone please review my work and explain my mistake or the information I am missing? Thank you.

The solution I worked out (wrong):
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that any row reduced form of $c_1 A_1+c_2A_2$ is still in $\text{Span}(A_1,A_2)$? In particular, if $c_1=1$ and $c_2=0$, you would need that the row reduced form of $A_1$, which is $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}$ is still in $\text{Span}(A_1,A_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The span of these matrices is$$S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,b=2a+\frac c2\wedge d=a+\frac c2\right\}$$It is clear that both of your matrices belong to $S$. Therefore, the space they span is a subsapce of $S$. But your matrices are linearly independent and $\dim S=2$. Therefore, the space spanned by your matrices is $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using only matrix sum, instead of calculating with matrices, you can calculate with vectors (so $A_1 = (1,2,0,1)$, $A_2 = (0,1,2,1)$ and calculate the span as the span in $R^4$ (or whatever field you consider)- this is actually what you've at the end finished with (system of 4 linear equations with 4 variables), hence a problem in $R^4$ rather than in a matrix ring..

Looking at your solution, it seems to me that you have a typo at the very beggining - the $y$ entry is equal to $2 c_2 + 0 c_1$.